# Overload += operator for two differents private attributes

Tags: c++

Is it possible to overload the += operator for two differents private attributes in a class ?

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
const int &Test::operator+=(const int &rhs)
{
   *this = *this + rhs;
   return *this;
}
```

Here is my class :

```
class Test
{
   private:
      int _n;
      int _n2;
   public:
      int getN();
      void setN(int n);
      int getN2();
      void setN2(int n);
      const int &operator+=(const int &rhs);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to be able to use `+=` for `_n` and `_n2` independently.
Note that my examples are not complete. I left out initialization and other parts to reduce bloating.

**1) Encapsulate your `int`s**

```
class Number
{
public:
    Number& operator += (int rhs)
    {
        _n += rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    int get() const;
    void set(int n);

protected:
    int _n;
};

class Test
{
public:
    Number& n()
    { return _n; }

    const Number& n() const
    { return _n; }

    Number& n2()
    { return _n2; }

    const Number& n2() const
    { return _n2; }

private:
    Number _n;
    Number _n2;
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.n() += 24;  // add to _n
    t.n2() += 42; // add to _n2
    return 0;
}
```

**2) Use two seperate base classes**

```
class N
{
public:
    N& operator += (int rhs)
    {
        _n += rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    int getN() const;
    void setN(int n);

protected:
    int _n;
};

class N2
{
public:
    N2& operator += (int rhs)
    {
        _n2 += rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    int getN2() const;
    void setN2(int n);

protected:
    int _n2;
};

class Test
    : public N
    , public N2
{};

int main()
{
    Test t;

    // add to _n
    t.N::operator += (24);    // explicit operator
    static_cast<N&>(t) += 24; // explicit cast

    // add to _n2
    t.N2::operator += (42);    // explicit operator
    static_cast<N2&>(t) += 24; // explicit cast

    return 0;
}
```